# placing legend below a raster plot and getting rid of the rectangle surrounding raster plot

Tags: r

I am plotting a raster image from the data stored in a file by using the three lines of code given below. However, I wish to generate a legend (or color-chart) below the image. The default legend is generated on the right hand side. Any idea how I may get legend at desired location.
Secondly, I am getting a rectangle around the image which I don't require in the final plot. Please help me with these issues.

```
            temp_var<-raster(input)
    par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
    plot(temp_var,legend=F,axes=FALSE)
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fought with the rectangle in `plot()` method for `Raster*` objects.  I am sure there is a way to get rid of it, but you don't need to.  I have always used this workaround:

```
image(temp_var, axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
```

As for your legend, I believe you will have to build that manually to your specs.  Try:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2), 7, 1))
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
image(temp_var, axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
plot(c(0,1), c(0,1), type="n", xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE)
legend(0.1,0.9, legend=c(1:5), fill=rainbow(5), horiz=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used colorbar.plot with some success in the past. Disable the legend that plot(raster(x)) automatically inserts with legend=FALSE and then call colorbar.plot(), i.e.

```
plot(raster(x),legend=FALSE)
colobar.plot(...)
```

Comment: PS: The question was posted by a work colleague who accidentally used my logon to post the question. I'm not posting questions then answering them an hour later...